# smart table not displaying

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm new to AngularJS and Smart Table...I'm trying to work through a simple Smart Table example, but for some reason I can't seem to get my table data to display.

Here is my html:

```
    <body ng-controller="basicsCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>birth date</th>
        <th>balance</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
        <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
        <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
        <td>{{row.email}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Here is my js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smartTable.table']);

    app.controller('basicsCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.rowCollection = [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];
    scope.name = "World";
}]);
```

Here is my plunker code: 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/335mfrwqHQXewqXJ4N0I?p=preview

Thanks!

Shanna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easy fix

change this line:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smartTable.table']);
```

to this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);
```

and reorder your script tags in the index file so that angular is before smart table

here is the updated plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/vHCbrN0cKDplxqwT78kf?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

having a similar problem with the same example. What do u mean re-order my script tags?

```
<script src="scripts/NonLibScripts/ScheduleScript.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/NonLibScripts/DataScript.js"></script>
```

Is this not sufficient? I am trying to populate the smart table data from the DataScript.